# How to keep state between views in a storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard, mkmapview, state

I have a storyboard with 2 UIViewControllers, MapView and MenuView. The storyboard first shows MapView, which contains an MKMapView. A button on MapView shows MenuView. A button on MenuView comes back to MapView. This is happening via segues. When back from MenuView to MapView, all annotations and region information on the MKMapView is gone. Seems a new instance is created every time. What do I need to do to have MKMapView saving state between views?

Comment: Try researching this before you ask on SO . This is not a place to come and people to write your code for you. You need to try something by yourself and if it does not work come and ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

Define an object that manages the data model for your app.  Put all the state information into it and read it from there when you load a controller that needs it.  The app delegate can either create and provide an empty data model at startup or -- if you need it -- initialize one from information previously saved from earlier execution of your app.